# react-native: ToolbarAndroid not displaying title when logo is used

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to display the title when logo is used in toolbar android. Title is displayed in toolbar when logo is not populated.

Need logo to be aligned left, followed by title and then settings to the right. Is it possible?

```
return (
      <View>
      <ToolbarAndroid style={styles.toolbar}
      logo={require('../images/P.png')}
      title="Toolbar"
      actions={[{title: 'Settings', icon: require('../images/setting.png'),show:'always',showWithText:'true'} ]}
 />
      <Image source={require('../images/P.png')}  style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />

        <Text> This is home page. </Text>


        </View>
    )

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
toolbar: {
    height: 56,
    backgroundColor: '#4883da',
},
});
```

This is what I see with logo..

[image]

and here is the screenshot without logo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I used the original image as is without resizing it for app. The image size for the logo should be small(like a icon). When I resized the imaged to 36X36, it worked..